# How to create Test plan for dependent REST API's?

Tags: jmeter

I have 3 Rest API's, each one of them dependent on each other, how to create test plan for them, jmeter firing those urls non sequential order i want it in Sequential order, when i check on "view result tree" i am getting 403 error.

Answer (score 0):

Are they in the same thread group? If so, they ought to fire sequentially in order.

Answer (score 0):

If the three are dependent on each other you need to take following steps:

1. Add thread group
2. Put the API's one after the other based on the values and dependency.
3. Extract the value from the first API and pass it to the next using Post Processors like Regular Expression Extractor or JSON extractor.

You are seeing 403 which is related to forbidden access, it means that you are not allowed to access that particular URL or missing some authentication token or cookies or username/password.

So add the authorization manager to your test plan if that's missing and send appropriate values.

Comment: first i need to get token then Presentation, and conference. but jmeter firing "get token" in randomly so iam getting 403 error for  "get presentation"

Comment: You need to extract the token and pass it to the next request. Check the headers.